# Visual Studio: Is it possible to define custom functions for use in one's own Code Snippets?

Tags: visual-studio, function, code-snippets

I want to write a Visual Studio snippet which allows me to quickly create a class of the form:

```
public SomeClass
{
    public SomeType SomeProperty { get; private set; }
    public SomeClass(SomeType someProperty) { SomeProperty = someProperty; }
}
```

**I want the parameter on the constructor to have the same name as the property, but lower-cased. I don't want to have to type the name twice.** How do I do this?

I've already looked at the XML for snippets and I discovered that there are certain functions that can be used. For example, the built-in "switch" code snippet contains the following instruction:

```
<Function>GenerateSwitchCases($expression$)</Function>
```

According to [this MSDN documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242312%28VS.80%29.aspx), there are three built-in functions that you can use in this `<Function>` tag. Unfortunately, neither of them does what I want (lower-case the first letter). Is it possible to define a function that I can then use in my snippet?

Comment: Man, I was just trying to do almost the exact same thing!  Argh!

Comment: see this Answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663569/c-custom-code-snippet-functions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No this is not possible in Visual Studio today.  The definition and execution of snippet functions is directly controlled by the C# language service.  It is not currently an extensibility point.  It is being considered for a future version of the product though.

Comment: Is it? Are you sure? There is a comment on a Microsoft Connect post that said this is considered "for the next version", but that comment is from 2005 and there have been two next versions since...

Comment: For clarity, my comment was referring to your last sentence in which you claimed "It is being considered for a future version". I am unconvinced that this is the case.

Comment: @Timwii, I can assure you it's actively being considered for a future version of the product.  Like always no assurances can be made but it is something that we are investigating.

Comment: This post claims to have created such a custom function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730156

Comment: @Daryl: OP says it won't work for C#. If you read the last couple of comments, he explains.